# Node JS comparing variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I've created a simple multiplayer game using node.js and socket.io, I'm struggling with the smallest thing now, comparing the scores of the two players.

I obviously have them stored as variables, but I cannot compare them to determine a winner, I know it's something simple I'm not understanding but if anyone can help that would be great.

```
users[socket.id] = user;

socket.on('answer', function(data) {

    if (data.answer+')' == answers[user.currentQuestion]) {
        user.score += 5;
        socket.emit('update',user.score);
    } else {
        user.score -= 3;
        socket.emit('update',user.score);
    }


    if (user.currentQuestion++ === 8) {
        user.finished = true;

        servio.sockets.emit('getWinner', true);

    }

    socket.emit('next', movies[user.currentQuestion]);

});
```

I need to compare each clients user.score

Users are stored according to their socket.id

Comment: We need some code to help you with. You could use http://jsapp.us/ for example

Comment: Why is it that you can't compare them? Can you provide any relevant code? It's really hard to answer this question because the question is really ambiguous.

Comment: can't see the problem yet. Where do you store users? I only see a variable called `user` but where is the other "user" you want to compare to? I think we need more code

Comment: Can you please share the code that compares the score of your users? I only see an increase/decrease score block.

Comment: That's what I am trying to figure out, how do I compare the scores of the users?

Comment: You ll need to know the socket.id of the two user you want to compare, and then compare users[first_user_socket.id].score with users[second_user_socket.id]. But you assign user to users[socket.id] before getting the score, I think you ll need to update users before doing that.